# Quick way to jumble the order of an NSString?

Tags: objective-c, random, nsstring, nsmutablestring, anagram

Does anyone know of an existing way to change the order of an existing NSString or NSMutableString's characters? I have a workaround in mind anyway but it would be great if there was an existing method for it.

For example, given the string @"HORSE", a method which would return @"ORSEH", @"SORHE", @"ROHES", etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider this code:
.h File:

```
@interface NSString (Scrambling)

+ (NSString *)scrambleString:(NSString *)toScramble;

@end
```

.m File:

```
@implementation NSString (Scrambling)

+ (NSString *)scrambleString:(NSString *)toScramble {
   for (int i = 0; i < [toScramble length] * 15; i ++) {
      int pos = arc4random() % [toScramble length];
      int pos2 = arc4random() % ([toScramble length] - 1);
      char ch = [toScramble characterAtIndex:pos];
      NSString *before = [toScramble substringToIndex:pos];
      NSString *after = [toScramble substringFromIndex:pos + 1];
      NSString *temp = [before stringByAppendingString:after];
      before = [temp substringToIndex:pos2];
      after = [temp substringFromIndex:pos2];
      toScramble = [before stringByAppendingFormat:@"%c%@", ch, after];
   }
   return toScramble;
}

@end
```

Not the most beautiful code or execution, but gets the job done. There's probably a (const char *) way to do this, but this works fine for me. A quick test shows a 0.001021 second length for execution on my Mac.

Usage:

```
NSString *scrambled = [NSString scrambleString:otherString];
```

Code adapted from another language / pseudocode

Comment: arc4random_uniform(maxIntIndex) is a better random number generator if you're running the code on 10.7 or iOS 4.3+. arc4random() is still good though if you need to support anything older.

Comment: Ah, as I was compiling for 10.5, it did not appear in the "suggestions" menu. Good to know.

Comment: @HiGuy'CouleeApps'Smith thanks for your comment, I am having an issue with getting it to work though: **Semantic Issue: Class method '+scrambleString:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')**
Any idea how I can fix it? I've placed it in header and implementation files

Comment: That means it cannot find the method. Make sure you #import-ed the .h file and that the method is specified in the .h under "@interface NSString (Scrambling)"

Comment: To make this work better, with more characters, replace the `%c` with `%C` and change the type of `ch` to `unichar` (which is the return type of `characterAtIndex:`).

Comment: Is this a category or a class extension? I am noob.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Durstenfeld's variation of the [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

For a very long string, you could save a lot of CPU time and allocations by copying the unichars to a unichar buffer, then performing the transform using a c or c++ approach to swap characters. Note that the `UTF8String` is not the buffer you want to take, nor should you mutate it. Then create (or set) a new `NSString` from the shuffled buffer.

More info on the Fisher Yates algo and C and C++ implementations [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=fisher%20yates).