# Scramble an NSString reversibly without being able to store the original string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, encryption

Is there a quick and dirty way to scramble an `NSString` and then unscramble it?

```
// i.e.
NSString *helloWorld = @"Hello World!";
[helloWorld scrambled]; //helloWorld now = @"W olell!odh"

[helloWorld unscramble]; //helloWorld now = @"Hello World!"
```

I've already accomplished something similar to this with Base64 encryption, but it adds significant bloat to my string. I don't care about the security level of the scrambling in the slightest, it just needs to be re-ordered so that it isn't human-readable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [quick way to jumble the order of an nstring?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003182/quick-way-to-jumble-the-order-of-an-nstring)

Comment: @BoA that question doesn't have unscrambling in mind

Comment: Just save the original string to a variable and read it in the unscramble method?

Comment: @BoA won't work for what I'm trying to do

Comment: What idea do you have in mind then? How would the method know what the original string was? It can't just guess.

Comment: Need to know what you are trying to achieve in regards to unscrambling, given you can't even keep the original string for unscramble piece.

Comment: How about reversing it? That's easy to "unscramble". I think you need to specify how "scrambled" you need this.

Comment: Is the "bloat" actually causing performance problems, or does the base-64 encoding just look longer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't save the original string, your procedure has to have some kind of a known key so that it's reversible. You're also concerned about the amount of information added to the string, but you don't care about it being particularly hard to decode. I guess you're transmitting the string over the network.

My suggestion is this: use a [Cæsar cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher). ROT-13 is the most famous example. Every character in the set of possible input characters is lined up, and that list is paired with another in the same order, but with its start point shifted. The second list provides the output for each character. E.g.,

```
Original: A B C D E ...
Encoded:  F G H I J ...
```

(Don't forget punctuation!)

Your `"Hello, world!"` might come out something like this: `"Mjqqt; Btwqi&"`.

You can thus transmit the key easily by prepending the encoding for 'A' to the string: `"FMjqqt; Btwqi&"`, which is only one extra character. This provides no meaningful security whatsoever -- people solve these things over breakfast -- but it does look like gibberish at a glance.

Comment: and for anybody looking to implement a Caesar Cipher there's a great one already written on GitHub https://github.com/RyanBibby/Caesar-Cipher-iPhone-App

Answer (score 0):

Enter all the letters of the word in a array and randomize the array. Remember to save the word to a NSString so you can get it back.

```
NSString *myString = @"Hello Word";
NSArray *myWords = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@""];
 NSUInteger count = [myWords count];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    // Select a random element between i and end of array to swap with.
    NSInteger nElements = count - i;
    NSInteger n = (arc4random() % nElements) + i;
    [self exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
}
NSString *newWord;
for(NSString *string in myWords){
     newWord = [newWord stringByAppendingString:string];
}
```

Comment: This doesn't address the second part of the question, which is un-jumbling the letters

Comment: @danielbeard He can save the word to a NNString

Comment: But that won't work for what he is trying to do... Whatever that may be...

Comment: @Abdullah He stated in the comments that storing the original string as a variable is not an option (for some reason).

Comment: That would work for me, but I am not using it. I am just amused at how @BobYousuk is trying to get an answer to this question when all he is saying is "Nope. Doesn't work. Don't want it" when all of the suggestions are valid. He still hasn't said why saving to a string won't work and why he is saying no to these methods.